# drop column based on most frequent value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

You can start by saying wtf but I would like to if it's possible to drop a column based on a condition like:

```
 drop column if 1 of the unique values of that column represent 70% of the samples.
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
prng = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(prng.choice([1, 2, 3], p=[0.7, 0.15, 0.15], size=(100, 5)))
```

You can get the percentages of each unique value for each column by:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True)
Out: 
      0     1     2     3     4
1  0.77  0.73  0.78  0.62  0.70
2  0.09  0.14  0.07  0.18  0.12
3  0.14  0.13  0.15  0.20  0.18
```

Note that the first three columns have unique values with higher than 70% occurrence. You can check that by the maximum value for each column and pass that as a boolean array:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True).max() > 0.7
Out: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Now, if you only want to select the ones with <70% unique values, use:

```
df.loc[:, ~(df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True).max() > 0.7)]
Out: 
    3  4
0   1  1
1   3  1
2   3  1
3   2  3
4   2  1
...
```

Comment: Nice use of `apply()` (not often we can say that!).

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks. As far as I know there is no vectorized way of counting values in each column other than looping over the columns so I used apply.